# Why the Softkeyboard example doesn't work?

Tags: android

I want to create a custom keyboard for android.

So I am starting from the official softkeyboard [example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard).

So I have downloaded it and I have opened it with Android Studio.

But as you can see, there is no way to Run it ( the play button is grey instead of green ):

[image]

What do I have to do ?
This is not my first app, I have developed other simple apps that work perfectly.

Comment: The android samples aren't up to date so don't use gradle, when importing the project android studio hasn't created a gradle file for you, try creating a brand new project and manually copying the files in to that project

Answer (score 1):

there is no gradle file in that project so you cant run... create new project and copy your classes